# type object 'App' has no attribute 'notebook'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having problems calling the .tab method to rename my tab and trying to run it results in the error in the title. Not sure why it would recognize the notebook variable but not the method. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

conn = sqlite3.connect('loadout.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
    
        self.NewLoadoutBtn = ttk.Button(self, text="New Loadout",command=self.add_tab)
        self.NewLoadoutBtn.pack(anchor=W)

        self.EditLoadoutBtn = ttk.Button(self, text="Edit Loadout",command=self.add_tab)
        self.EditLoadoutBtn.pack(anchor=W)

        self.EditTankBtn = ttk.Button(self, text="Edit Tank",command=self.add_tab)
        self.EditTankBtn.pack(anchor=W)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()

    def add_tab(self):
        self.tab1 = Loadout(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.tab1,text="Loadout")
        self.notebook.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        self.NewLoadoutBtn.pack(anchor=E)
        self.EditLoadoutBtn.pack_forget()
        self.EditTankBtn.pack_forget()



class Loadout(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        customerquery = cur.execute("SELECT customers FROM misc")

        self.CustomerBox = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.CustomerBox.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.CustomerBox['values'] = customerquery.fetchall()
        self.CustomerBox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.UpdateTitle)

    def UpdateTitle(self,event):
        CBget = self.CustomerBox.get()
        App.notebook.tab(0, text=CBget)
        

my_app = App()
my_app.mainloop()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You never call the `add_tab` method.  It does not see the `notebook` variable; that's what it is complaining about.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I had changed it. I have the notebook variable in the __init__ function. Not sure if that's the best way to go about it but it lets me create endless seemingly unique tabs. But either way I still have the same problem. How do I go about calling it then?

Comment: The `App` variable you reference in `Loadout.UpdateTitle` is not an instance of the class `App`, because you didn't initialize it. A class has no accessible variables until it has been initialized. Try passing an `App` instance as an argument for `Loadout` when you initiallize it, and giving `Loadout` a `self.app` variable for referencing it.

Comment: It would really help if this example didn't depend on a database. You should replace the db code with some hard-coded data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
App.notebook.tab(0, text=CBget)
```

`App` is a class, not an instance of the class. The error is correct that the class does not have a `notebook` attribute because that attribute is only created once the class has been instantiated.

That line of code needs to use the instance of `App`:

```
my_app.notebook.tab(0, text=CBget)
```

However, it's not the best idea to rely on a global variable. It would probably be better to pass the instance in, perhaps like this:

```
class App(Tk):
    ...
    def add_tab(self):
        self.tab1 = Loadout(self.notebook, app=self)

class Loadout(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.app = kwargs.pop("app")       
        Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        ...

    def UpdateTitle(self,event):
        ...
        self.app.notebook.tab(0, text=CBget)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still trying to wrap my head around class inheritance but I think I'm starting to get it now.